# Multiple document types in SDI application (or just a capability of MDI?)

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi, sdi

I have a (maybe ridiculous) question about MFC - can an SDI application support multiple document *types*? (Along with showing the "choose-document" dialogue when creating a new document, but that's not absolutely necessary and I could handle it myself.) What I want to do is my app to behave like modern office programs, that is each new document (of some type) residing in its own instance of the application, instead of sharing a common space with other open documents (the concept of MDI).

If SDI cannot give such functionality (which my recent experimentation suggests), could someone advice me how to handle the "open" command under MDI to open the file in a new instance of the application? (The same then applies to the "new" command.)

Answer (score 1):

MFC calls this application type "Multiple top-level documents", and you can select it in MFC App Wizard:

[image: MFC App Wizard]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately, I'm using an Express edition of VS2010, so the Wizard isn't there. Do you think you could share somewhere what it produces? Would be highly appreciated, because I'm not much keen about re-inventing the code... :-) Thanks if that's possible.

Comment: I sure can share the generated project, but let me first suggest that you install Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition that is a **FREE** version of VS2013 Pro, with all of its features. Then you can play with the wizards to explore different options.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add the document tamplates using [CWinApp::AddDocTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dwece4tk.aspx)
The msdn link provides only the example with `CMultiDocTemplate`, so I've included here the example with `CSingleDocTemplate` that is generated when you create a new project with visual studio.

```
// Register the application's document templates.  Document templates
//  serve as the connection between documents, frame windows and views
CSingleDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
pDocTemplate = new CSingleDocTemplate(
    IDR_MAINFRAME,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CSDITestDoc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame),       // main SDI frame window
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CSDITestView));
if (!pDocTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);
```

Comment: That's what I was experimenting with - adding multiple types into a SingleDocTemplate. The app crashed with adding the second type...

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/doc_view/viewmanagement/article.php/c3283/SDI-Interface-with-MultiViews-and-MultiSplitters.htm